# What two dimensional data structure should I use which supports fixed size in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I'm writing a game which has a board:

```
 ________
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
```

I want to push items in each column separately from the top:

```
 ________
|__|__|X_| // <-- pushToTop(2, item);
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
```

and/or from the bottom:

```
 ________
|__|__|X_|
|__|__|__|
|__|__|X_| // <-- pushToBottom(2, item);
```

I already have an implementation which uses a 2 dimensional array which works perfectly. My problem is that I have a set of functions with code like this:

```
        List<Card> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Card[] column : board) {
            for (Card card : column) {
                // do something
            }
        }
        return result;
```

and I want to use `map`/`filter`/`reduce` from the *Java 8 Stream API* instead of the nested for loops to process my `board`.

My question is that what `Collection` can I use which works like an array (fixed size, I can add items based on index, I can remove items without changing the size of the array)?

**Clarification:** The main problem is that a primitive array can't be treated as a `Collection` thus does not take part in the *Stream* abstraction.

Comment: What's wrong with a 2D array?  If it's fixed size...

Comment: I added some clarification.

Comment: You could use a `Map`, but you would need control the key value so it represented a cell, row or column correctly.  There would be nothing stopping you from "adding" more cells if you didn't manage it.  You could use an `ArrayList`, which is just an array wrapped in a `List`, but you'd have to pre-fill the `ArrayList` and make sure you use `set` and not `add`. You could roll your own `List` to meet your needs.  It's not a matter of which is the best "Collection" to use, but which meets your requirements

Comment: There's really none in the standard API. You can either make your own Matrix class that implements Collection (this is what I did some time ago, just for fun) or use [some other already available implementation](https://java-matrix.org/).

Comment: As an aside, you can stream arrays with `Arrays#stream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Java 8 specific, but it sounds like you'd benefit from [Guava's `Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table); notably, [`ArrayTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html).

It gives you a more convenient API to add and retrieve things at specific coordinates, and since you know the size of your world by the time you get the object, you don't have to worry as much about space or creating a bunch of awkward objects to tie everything in.

Comment: Right.  I doubt you could accomplish this with just one Collection class anyway, as this is fairly complex and fiddly.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things to consider:

1. **Stream API compliance**

   - If you want to use the `Stream` interface, you have to either directly implement it or provide a transformation method that return a `Stream` instance (better way).
2. **Internal implementation**

   - Internal implementation is not that important until you consider to support streams ideally in the easiest way, which is somehow express your data structure as a `Collection` instance and let the `Collection` to take care of the transformation into `Stream`.
3. **The iteration order**

   - It's not directly obvious but the iteration order might dictate the internal data structure format. The easiest way will be to iterate over rows from top to bottom.

If the assumption on *iteration order* is correct, then the easiest way will be to use `ArrayList<T>` internally and always recompute the coordinates from your matrix into the `ArrayList` index. The iteration order of your stream will be the same as the order of the `Iterator` from your data structure.

```
interface MyType<T> {
    void pushtoTop(int, T);
    void pushToBottom(int, T);

    Stream stream();
}
```